Hierarchical agglomerative clustering with complete linkage to cluster a 1dimensional dataset
I'm currently working on hierarchical agglomerative clustering and am familiar with its application to datasets presented in tables. However, I'm unsure how to apply this method to a 1-dimensional dataset, especially when clustering data points represented on a graph x axis only. Can anyone please guide me on how to use single and complete linkage in hierarchical agglomerative clustering for 1-dimensional datasets? Additionally, I would appreciate it if you could provide examples or methods that could help me understand how to approach similar problems in the future.
